# How to add Data_augmentation to a CNN Sequential model with CIFAR10 dataset

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, sequential, data-augmentation

####New to the stack overflow community.  Thank you in advance for everyone's help####

I am trying to add data augmentation to a CNN Sequential Model to see how it affects on generalization.  I have tried adding the augmentation as a preprocessing step and also during the build.  neither step is working for me.  This is the last error I received: InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error keep happening while trying to Compile and Train my model.
How can I add data augmentation to this model?

```
#Data Augmentation
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.1),
    tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(0.2)
], name= 'data_augmentation')
```

```
#Build CNN Model
k.clear_session()
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    data_augmentation,
    Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape=x_train_norm.shape[1:]),
    MaxPool2D((2,2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    MaxPool2D((2,2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), activation=tf.nn.relu),
    MaxPool2D((2,2), strides=2),
    Dropout(0.3),
    #GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
    #Flatten(),
    Dense(units=384, activation=tf.nn.softmax),#kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(0.001)),
    BatchNormalization(),
    Dropout(0.3),
    Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

#model.summary()


#Compile and train

history, model = compile_train_model(model,
                                     x_train_norm, y_train_split,
                                     x_valid_norm, y_valid_split)
```

### Epoch 1/200

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 33>()
31 #Compile and train
32
---> 33 history, model = compile_train_model(model,
34                                      x_train_norm, y_train_split,
35                                      x_valid_norm, y_valid_split)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
51   try:
52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'Equal' defined at (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/colab_kernel_launcher.py", line 37, in 
ColabKernelApp.launch_instance()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in 
lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
ret = callback()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
self.ctx_run(self.run)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 377, in dispatch_queue
yield self.process_one()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 250, in wrapper
runner = Runner(ctx_run, result, future, yielded)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in **init**
self.ctx_run(self.run)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
yielded = self.gen.send(value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
self.do_execute(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
result = self._run_cell(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
return runner(coro)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async*=asy)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 33, in <cell line: 33>
history, model = compile_train_model(model,
File "", line 12, in compile_train_model
history = model.fit(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1742, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1322, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1303, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1085, in train_step
return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1179, in compute_metrics
self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 605, in update_state
metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 723, in update_state
matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/accuracy_metrics.py", line 459, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
matches = metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(y_true, y_pred)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 968, in sparse_categorical_matches
matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())
Node: 'Equal'
required broadcastable shapes
[[{{node Equal}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3170]

I tried adding data augmentation as a preprocessing step and in the building of the model.

I was expecting to get better generalization with droppout.

Comment: Take a look at [How to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)